# Getting META tag Attributes PHP From URL

Tags: php

Hi i am having an issue when scraping meta tags from a url, the code works on php fiddle but on my server it will return data from what appears to be a different file, a number of the tag properties are different. For example the 'og:url' meta tag  returns the tld (domain) only without the path passed. In the browser and phpfiddle the same code returns the full url, including the path as desired. It appears to be treating the request from the server differently.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta ) { 
    echo $meta->getAttribute('property'). "=>" .$meta->getAttribute('content').";\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? What are they? What line do they happen on?

Comment: i am not given any errors, just returns empty. It is strange it returns them on some urls and not others, but the tags are there and accurate, thanks for the reply.

Comment: remove the the `@` so you can see the dom errors

Comment: I removed the @ and it is not returning any errors, maybe there is something i am missing? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: var_dump() returns string(0) for the missing values, they are available and correct. Thanks for the reply

Comment: "They are available and correct" - how do you know? What happens when you `var_dump($html)`?  Also - you keep reporting no errors - do you have error reporting turned on? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the file.

Comment: The var_dump returns object(DOMDocument)#9 (34){...}. I can't see why the same code works fine on phpfiddle, obviously the setup. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-meta-tags.php
May it works.
Should work with curl too, but I havent enough experience with curl.
I hope I could help you.